# How to combine summary and detail informatoin on SSRS report

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

Have a monthly report that lists associate name, date, the type of work they completed and how many. This report is being rendered in Excel and produces a separate tab for each associate with their information.

I'm trying to modify the report so it will provide a summary at the bottom of each page, specific for that associate, to show: Type of work, total count. 
Here is an example of the desired outcome.

[image: Report sample]

I have a separate dataset that provides the summary data I need, I just can't figure out how to combine this with the detail report and have it produce separate tabs for each associate and display the summary for each associate on the same tab.

Any assistance you can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible, you are on the correct version as ssrs 2005 this was not possible. The the PageName property of the Tablix member, you group on the the value there

Comment: Not following your suggestion. Could you be a little more specific or provide screen shots? Are you saying to set the page name property of the tablix that pointing to my summary data set?

Comment: Let me add some clarification to my request. In the above screen shot, rows 1-12 represent the monthly detail for the associate. In my current design, when I run the report and export it to excel, I get a single spreadsheet with 12 tabs (1 tab for each associate). What I'm trying to do is add a summary section (as displayed on rows 14 - 16) to the report design. The desired outcome is still the same 12 tabs showing both the summary and detail information. Can this be accomplished? If so, how would I do that? Thank you.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thanks